# ¿Cómo contar numero de ocurrencias de cada elemento de una lista?

Tags: python, lista, contador

Como contar la ocurrencia cada elemento i en la lista:

```
A=[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4, 1]

for i in A:
    print([A].count(i))
```

Para obtener:

> 3
>
> 1
>
> 1
>
> 2

Answer (score 1):

`[A]` crea una nueva lista con `A` como único elemento.

Debería ser:

```
print(A.count(i))
```

El problema es que cuenta las ocurrencias por cada elemento en el arreglo. Así que obtienes salidas repetidas:

> 3 
> 1 
> 1 
> 2 
> 3 
> 2 
> 3

---

Para evitarlo, puedes obtener un [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) a partir de la lista. Un `set` tiene la particularidad de que no admite duplicados.

Entonces iteras sobre el `set`. De modo que se imprimirá una sola vez por cada elemento diferente.

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4, 1]
conjunto = set(A)

for i in conjunto:
    print(A.count(i))
```

Podes probarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/31HBViHaUEfBSEfBWEfBREfBEELGcnEl5@dlleaV5ANVFKeWaDhqcnGl5RcpZCpk5ik4WnEpAEFBUWYeUEYvOR@oUCNTU/P/fwA).

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar un diccionario para contar los elementos. El método [dict.get](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) intenta extraer el valor solicitado, si no existe le pone un valor por defecto, en este caso `0`, y luego se le suma `1`.

```py
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4, 1]
contador = {}
for elem in A:
    contador[elem] = contador.get(elem, 0) + 1

print(contador) # --> {1: 3, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar Counter del paquete collections:

```py
from collections import Counter 

A=[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4, 1]

contador = Counter(A)

print(type(contador))
print(contador)
```

```bash
<class 'collections.Counter'>
Counter({1: 3, 4: 2, 2: 1, 3: 1})
```

```py
for i,v in contador.items(): 
  print(f"el nro {v} se repite: {i} veces")
```

```bash
el nro 3 se repite: 1 veces
el nro 1 se repite: 2 veces
el nro 1 se repite: 3 veces
el nro 2 se repite: 4 veces
```